# Javascript get form array values

Tags: javascript, for-loop, append, forms

I have a form that is set up so that there is an add button so my user can submit multiple people at once to the site.

At first the form has an input to fill out the persons name one example below

```
<input type="text" name="name[]" value="Name" />
```

If they hit the add button another one is appended so that I'm left with the following

```
<input type="text" name="name[]" value="Name" /> 
<input type="text" name="name[]" value="Name" />
```

Then when they hit submit I'm trying to get the values of each name in Javascript and loop through them I've tried this but it's not working

```
var inputs = document.getElementById('formIDhere').getElementsByTagName('name');
alert(inputs.length);
```

I never get the alert and if I just set up a loop like this

```
for(int i=0; i<inputs.length; i++)
```

Nothing happens, any help on looping through the values of name[] in javascript would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why don't you show the code for the submit button?

Comment: FYI: getElementsByTagName("name") is looking for <name></name>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you could try:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("#formIDHere input[name='name[]']");
alert(inputs.length);
for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Simple approach:**

```
var names=document.getElementsByName('name[]');

for(key=0; key < names.length; key++)  {
    alert(names[key].value);

    //your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[...document.querySelector("#FORMID").elements['name[]']].map(el=>el.value); 
// Returns ["name","name",...]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `document.getElementById('formIDhere').elements.name`.

It will give you an array with all the values.

Answer (score 0):

your mistake is using `getElementsByTagName`, which is asking for a tag called `<name>`, and of course you don't have it, try setting a class to the input for example and fetch it using jquery `$('className')` which will surely get the result correct, or using dom you can still use 
`document.getElementById('form').elements.name` but still this way might not be cross browser safe unless tested carefully

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByTagName` returns the array of elements whoose tag name is specified in argument.
In html there is no element whoose tag name is `name`.

`name` is an attribute given to html elements.
To get elements based on name you can use

```
var ele=document.getElementsByName('whatevername');
```

`ele` will contain the array of elements whose name is specified. Then you can use your loop to iterate through each element.

Answer (score 0):

this is what form elements is for

```
var inputs = document.getElementById('formIDhere').elements["name[]"];
alert(inputs.length);
for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `JQuery` you could try:

```
   var arr = $('#frmId').serializeArray();
```

`serialize` method offers several options that you could check in: https://api.jquery.com/serializearray/