# jQuery: get all values from input array and calculate them to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple input arrays (see snippet). I need to calculate all of the entered values to a variables. It is an invoice creation, so I want to know the total price of all items with discount. How can I achieve this?

This is what I have for now:

```js
$('#addNewPosition').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#positions').append('<input type="text" name="item[]" placeholder="Item" class="form-control">\n' +
                '            <input type="number" step="any" name="price[]" placeholder="Price" class="form-control">\n' +
                '            <input type="number" name="item_discount[]" placeholder="Discount, %" class="form-control">\n' +
                '            <input type="number" step="any" name="quantity[]" placeholder="Quantity" class="form-control">\n' +
                '            <input type="text" name="quantity_index[]" placeholder="Unit" class="form-control">\n' +
                '            <input type="text" name="description[]" placeholder="Description" class="form-control">\n');
        });

// Get the number of all items added:
var count = $("input[name='item[]']").map(function() {
  return $(this).val();
}).get().length;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="positions">
  <input type="number" step="any" name="price[]" placeholder="Price" class="form-control">
  <input type="number" name="item_discount[]" placeholder="Discount, %" class="form-control">
  <input type="number" step="any" name="quantity[]" placeholder="Quantity" class="form-control">
  <input type="text" name="quantity_index[]" placeholder="Unit" class="form-control">
  <input type="text" name="description[]" placeholder="Description" class="form-control">
  <a href="#" id="addNewPosition" class="btn btn-green">Add new</a>
</div>
```

All I want to achieve is to calculate the total price: total = ((each field's price) - discount, %) * quantity

Is there any way I can do that? Kind regards

Comment: when you want it to show? after a button click or auto updating when user interact with the inputs?

Comment: Where do you want to see the result? In console? In some element?

Comment: Why are you using `.length` That is giving you the array length you just created. You should use reduce() after the map

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010177/javascript-get-form-array-values

Comment: This is in my modal and then I want to pass it to the parent, @Anton. And I am using length to determine the length of the array, cause I thought I could use `for` loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delegate the input event in order to compute the total each time a price or a discount changes.

In order to achive your result you can combine [.map()](https://api.jquery.com/map/) with [.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
$('#addNewPosition').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#positions').append('<div class="form-group">' +
            '<div class="col-sm-1"></div><div class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" name="item[]" placeholder="Item" class="form-control"></div>\n' +
            '            <div class="col-sm-1"><input type="number" step="any" name="price[]" placeholder="Price" class="form-control"></div>\n' +
            '            <div class="col-sm-1"><input type="number" name="item_discount[]" placeholder="Discount, %" class="form-control"></div>\n' +
            '            <div class="col-sm-1"><input type="number" step="any" name="quantity[]" placeholder="Quantity" class="form-control"></div>\n' +
            '            <div class="col-sm-1"><input type="text" name="quantity_index[]" placeholder="Unit" class="form-control"></div>\n' +
            '            <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" name="description[]" placeholder="Description" class="form-control"></div>\n' +
            '</div>');
});

$(document).on('input', 'input[name="price[]"], input[name="item_discount[]"], input[name="quantity[]"]', function (e) {
    var price = $('input[name="price[]"]').map(function (idx, ele) {
        return $(ele).val().trim().length == 0 ? 0 : parseFloat($(ele).val().trim());
    }).get();
    var discount = $('input[name="item_discount[]"]').map(function (idx, ele) {
        return $(ele).val().trim().length == 0 ? 0 : parseFloat($(ele).val().trim());
    }).get();
    var quantity = $('input[name="quantity[]"]').map(function (idx, ele) {
        return $(ele).val().trim().length == 0 ? 0 : parseFloat($(ele).val().trim());
    }).get();
    var total = price.reduce(function (a, v, i) {
        return a + (v - (v * discount[i] / 100)) * quantity[i];
    }, 0);
    console.log('total=' + total);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="positions">
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <input type="number" step="any" name="price[]" placeholder="Price" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <input type="number" name="item_discount[]" placeholder="Discount, %" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <input type="number" step="any" name="quantity[]" placeholder="Quantity" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <input type="text" name="quantity_index[]" placeholder="Unit" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="text" name="description[]" placeholder="Description" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <a href="#" id="addNewPosition" class="btn btn-green">Add new</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! There is no quantity, and I tried to add a 
`var quantity = $('input[name="quantity[]"]').map(function(idx, ele) {
                return $(ele).val().trim().length == 0 ?  0 : parseFloat($(ele).val().trim());
            }).get();`
and in the return `return (a - (v * discount[i] / 100)) * quantity;`, but the total is NaN

Comment: I've entered `123` (price), `10` (discount), `3` (amount) into your code snippet and it shows me `total=1230`. Seems strange

Answer (score 1):

Here's another workaround. But this is in VanillaJS, you can just turn it into Jquery.

```js
(function(){

  let addNewButton = document.getElementById("addLineButton");

  let baseItem = document.getElementById("_base");
  let container = document.getElementById('content');

  function createItem(idNumber){
    let newItemNode = baseItem.cloneNode(true);
    newItemNode.id = "_" + idNumber;
    container.insertBefore(newItemNode, document.getElementById("totals"));

    document.querySelectorAll(".editable").forEach((input)=>{
      input.addEventListener("keyup", (event)=>{
        performCalculation(input);
      });
    })
  }

  addNewButton.addEventListener('click', (event)=>
  {
    let currentItemCount = document.getElementsByClassName("item-container").length;
    createItem(currentItemCount);
  });

  function performCalculation(input)
  {
    var cId = input.closest("tr.item-container").id; // container id <tr>
    var qtyVal = document.querySelector(`#${cId} .quantity input`).value;
    var priceVal = document.querySelector(`#${cId} .price input`).value;
    var discountVal = document.querySelector(`#${cId} .discount input`).value;
    var lineTotalElement = document.querySelector(`#${cId} .total input`);
    if(qtyVal && discountVal && priceVal)
    {
      lineTotalElement.value= Number((priceVal * (1 - (discountVal/100))) * qtyVal).toFixed(2);
      performTotal();
    }
  }

  function performTotal()
  {
    let element = document.getElementById("totalPrice");
    let totalPrice = Number(0);
    document.querySelectorAll(".item.total input").forEach((linePrice)=>{
      totalPrice += Number(linePrice.value);
    });
    element.value = totalPrice.toFixed(2);
  }
})();
```

```css
tr input{
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}
tr td:last-child input{
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}


tr#totals{
  border-top: thin solid gray;
  padding: 0.25rem 0; 

}
#_base{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="./src/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
</head>

<body>
    <table class="table table-light">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" class="item description">Description</th>
                <th scope="col" class="item quantity">Quantity</th>
                <th scope="col" class="item price">Price</th>
                <th scope="col" class="item discount">Discount</th>
                <th scope="col" class="item total">Line Total</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="content">
            <tr id="_base" class="item-container">
                <th scope="col" class="item description">
                    <input class="editable" placeholder="Description" />
                </th>
                <th scope="col" class="item quantity">
                    <input class="editable" placeholder="Quantity" />
                </th>
                <th scope="col" class="item price">
                    <input class="editable" placeholder="Unit Price" />
                </th>
                <th scope="col" class="item discount">
                    <input class="editable" placeholder="Discount" />
                </th>
                <th scope="col" class="item total">
                    <input disabled />
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="totals" class="item-container">
                <th scope="col" >
                </th>
                <th scope="col" >
                </th>
                <th scope="col" >
                </th>
                <th scope="col" >
                    Line Total
                </th>
                <th scope="col" class="item overallTotal">
                    <input id="totalPrice" disabled />
                </th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button id="addLineButton">Add Line</button>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="src/index.js">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

[Find Codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-sky-977ef?file=/index.html)